# Pattern for Spring-MVC stateful interaction

Tags: forms, spring-mvc

Today I was doing this thing with Spring:

- Have a page with a form and a chance to choose one item related to the form.
- If you push "Choose item" the app will save somehow what you typed in the form, go to another page, let you choose the thing.

  - When you are back to the form it's filled with what you wrote before going to the other page, plus the item chosen.

Seems easy, but you have to take into account that for some stupid reason the user could open the page where you choose the item (maybe because of a bookmark, or because he pressed the back button 10 times to play). You know what I mean. I tried many ways, mainly based on HttpSession... I don't like any of those. None of them seems elegant. I was even thinking of using a hidden form in the other page, but given that it is not unique to this "flow" (I mean you can go to the item choose page from others as well), I will have to worry about conflicts and so on.

So what would be the preferred way for you? Suggestions?

Comment: Skaffman, you always correct my english.... is it that bad :D ??

Answer (score 4):

Go around the problem instead of solving it. You can use a **modal javascript div popup** where the user can pick the item she wants. The contents of this div can be **loaded via ajax** (separate Spring MVC controller called with Http GET). Once the selection has been made, you close the popup (hide the div) and copy the value into the original form. Done.

**No need to store the state anywhere.**

Comment: This is probably the best solution, I thought about this and I know how to use it. But I'd like to get a good pattern for the other situation, that I've seen in so many web apps.

Comment: Well, Spring WebFlow supports the concept of sub-flows, which pause the current flow and return to it afterwards. But this is a lot of overkill, compared to the simple solution I presented above.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Spring Web Flow.

```
     Spring Web Flow compliments the Spring MVC.
```

Here is link to [Spring Web Flow Demo](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/05/18/spring-web-flow-java-one-2007-demo/)